# SQL: how to select text with the shortest, longest and average length text message in one query?

Tags: sql

Question: Find the tweet(s) with the shortest, longest and average length text message.

My sql query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Tweet
WHERE text = ANY (SELECT max(length(text)), min(length(text)), avg(length(text))
                  FROM Tweet
                 )
```

But the result shows:
OperationalError: near "SELECT": syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close.  But a `JOIN` is a better approach:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM Tweet t JOIN
     (SELECT max(length(text)) as maxt, min(length(text)) as mint, 
             avg(length(text)) as avt
      FROM Tweet
     ) tt
     on length(t.text) in (tt.maxt, tt.mint, tt.avgt);
```

I don't think `avg(length(text))` makes sense unless you take the floor or convert it to an integer somehow.  That said, some databases will return an integer for an `avg()`, so it might work in your database.

Your query doesn't work because the subquery returns three columns; however, it is only being compared to one.  Some databases allow tuples with `in`.  Even so, the length of the operands don't match.